# Uncaught TypeError: json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy teniendo un problema muy extraño y no lo entiendo, ayer funcionaba bien, y ahora me esta reventando toda la pagina web con el mismo error, os especifico un poco mas:

Este es el error:

```
backoffice.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html is not a function
at Object.success (backoffice.js:37)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at x (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Os adjunto `backoffice.js:37`:

```
            boxhtml+="<div id='form-main'>";
            boxhtml+="<p class='asunto'>";
            boxhtml+="<input name='asunto' type='text' class='feedback-input' placeholder='Asunto' id='asunto' value='"+json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html().replace("'","`")+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</p>";
            boxhtml+="<p class='text'>";
```

Exactamente el error me lo marca aquí:

```
"value='"+json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html().replace("'","`")+"' />";
```

Os pongo el código completo si queréis profundizar mas en el error:

```
function modificarComunicado(id){
     $.get("modules/backoffice/comunicaciones/leer_comunicacion.php?idcomunicacion=" + id, function(data){
        if(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            url="functions/recogidadatos.php";
              urlReturn="modules/backoffice/comunicaciones/gestion_comunicaciones.php";
            var imagen=json.comunicado.IMAGEN;
            var longitud = imagen.length;

            var boxhtml ="";


            boxhtml+="<form action=''name='comunicationUpdate' onload='cargaeditor();' id='comunicationUpdate' method='post'";
            boxhtml+="<div id='box-modificar-comunicado' class='capa-fondo-caja capa-fondo-caja-backoffice centered-absolute'>";
            boxhtml+="<div class='header-caja-fondo-backoffice'>";

            boxhtml+="<h2><span class='icon-document-edit size-icons-table-backoffice'></span>Modificación comunicado</h2>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";

            boxhtml+="<div id='form-main'>";
            boxhtml+="<p class='asunto'>";
            boxhtml+="<input name='asunto' type='text' class='feedback-input' placeholder='Asunto' id='asunto' value='"+json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html().replace("'","`")+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</p>";

            boxhtml+="<p class='text'>";
            boxhtml+="<textarea name='comunicacion' class='feedback-input' id='comunicacion' placeholder='comunicacion'>"+json.comunicado.CUERPO.html().replace("'","`")+"</textarea>";
            boxhtml+="</p>";


            boxhtml+="<input name='id' type='hidden' class='feedback-input' placeholder='id' id='id' value='"+id+"' />";

            boxhtml+="<input name='idNotificacion' type='hidden' class='feedback-input' placeholder='idNotificacion' id='idNotificacion' value='"+json.comunicado.IDNOT+"' />";

            boxhtml+="<div id='contenedor'>";
            boxhtml+="<div class='fecha'>";
            boxhtml+="Fecha Inicio:<input name='fecha_ini' type='date' class='feedback-input fecha' id='fecha' value='"+json.comunicado.FECHA_INI+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</div>";

            boxhtml+="<div class='fecha'>";
            boxhtml+="Fecha Fin:<input name='fecha_fin' type='date' class='feedback-input fecha' id='fecha' value='"+json.comunicado.FECHA_FIN+"' />";
            boxhtml+="</div>";

            boxhtml+="<div class='department'>";
            boxhtml+= "Departamento:<input type='text' name='areadep' value='"+json.comunicado.CREADOR+"' id='areadep' readonly/>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";

            boxhtml+="<p class='text'>";
            boxhtml+="<input type='file' name='archivo' value='imagen' id='imagen'/> Imagen insertada anteriormente: "+imagen.substring(57,longitud);
            boxhtml+="</p>";

            boxhtml+="<div id='button-blue' onclick='ejecutarJQueryComunicado(url,urlReturn)' class='submit'>";
            boxhtml+="MODIFICAR";
            boxhtml+="</div>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";
            boxhtml+="</div>";
            boxhtml+="</form>";

            añadirCapaFondo(boxhtml);


           $("#comunicationUpdate").ready(function(){
              tinymce.remove();
              tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' ,
                plugins:"advlist"
            });
           });

        }
    });
}
```

Si tenéis alguna idea de porque me esta saltando este error, por favor decirmelo

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código completo?

Comment: heeyy hola @Error404 sii ahora la edito ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás manejando un objeto y lo estás usando como una función. Creo que con que pongas solo `json.comunicado.ASUNTO` en lugar de `json.comunicado.ASUNTO.html()` debería funcionar sin problemas (y en el que tienes debajo de CUERPO también).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta funciona correctamente